# Using a div class below an LI to call jQuery .on click fucntion

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists, toggle

I have an unordered list that I use jQuery to toggle open and close.  It works just fine when any content within the li is clicked.  However, I am trying to get a < div class="prod_cat" > within the li to be the toggle.  I've tried several iterations without success.  I have searched for a solution without success.  I'm sure it's something simple that's just slipped by me.

This works with ALL content within the li.

```
$("li").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();       
});
```

I've tried and failed to get the following to work.

This is a simple version of the HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div class="prod_cat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
      Main Category
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="prod_cat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
            Sub
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <div class="prod_cat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                  Sub
                  <ul>
                     <li>Sub
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Sub
         </li>
      </ul>
   <li>Commissionable
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="prod_cat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
      Countries
      <ul>
         <li>CA
         </li>
         <li>US
         </li>
         <li>AU
         </li>
         <li>NZ
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Additional information that might be relevant:

To close the UL's I use this as well.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("li").find('ul').hide();
});
```

It occurs to me after seeing one of the answers (which works other than when the div is clicked all UL's below it are open, children of children, etc.) that perhaps not all UL's are being closed on load. Maybe just the top one is.  If I was certain that was the issue, this might be 2 issues in 1 and I would need to create a new question. However, I am not sure.

[image]

When the + beside the 1 is clicked 6 and 8 should show, but 9 and 10 are also showing up.

EDITED:  Here's a crude jsfiddle reproduction of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/eypxLLzc/2/

UPDATED:  This is a jsfiddle representing the answer that worked for me. https://jsfiddle.net/eypxLLzc/3/

```
$(this).parent("li").find('> ul').toggle();
```

Using this like to toggle was the ultimate solution.  Without the > it will toggle ALL ul.  The > toggles just level 1 children.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Updated with a simple HTML UL.

Comment: ul is not div child, as it seems: https://jsfiddle.net/eypxLLzc/  you need another selector....

Comment: @nevermind I couldn't get that to work in my application. Not sure why.  wim-mertens answer is super close.  It works to the extent that it toggles  from the div, but it opens all children, not just the first line children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(".prod_cat").on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent("li").find('ul').toggle();       
    });
```

Comment: Questions was edited.  Your answer is super close... but, it opens all children, not just level 1 children.

Comment: Didyou try this?
    $(this).parent("li").find('> ul').toggle();

Comment: Not sure if this works actually.... can you add a class to the first ul? Or use .closest('ul')

Comment: @RedSands did you try the > selector?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$(".prod_cat").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

however, it is bad practice to base your code on the HTML structure, better to use direct assignment like so:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <div class="prod_cat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
  Main Category
  <ul>
     <li>
        <a class="prod_cat" target="#lvl1" rel="toggleList"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        Sub
        <ul id="lvl1">
           <li>
              <a class="prod_cat" target="#lvl1_1" rel="toggleList"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
              Sub
              <ul id="lvl1_1">
                 <li>Sub
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>Sub
     </li>
  </ul>
```

with

```
$("[rel='toggleList']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.target).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but it didn't work. Ultimately, @wim-mertens answer did the trick.   Under the circumstances presented, I do not have the luxury of adding id to the UL.  It's dynamically generated UL list that I'm dealing with, so I was unable to test your 2nd answer, which under other circumstances may actually work.